# How to provide large data at operator execution, arguments or otherwise?

Tags: python, objects, operator

**What I want to do:**

Create an addon that "inflates" 2D polygons into 3D meshes (using more ways than just extrude). There will be an option to select predefined polygons as an enum type (letters as well as basic geometries).
An option to select a CSV or json file that will load a shape from file.
It should be able to take any size of array of 2D coordinates(10 to 1000 pairs normally), defining a polygon in 2D using python scripting/console

This operator will be added to the "add mesh" context menu (shift-A).
However, when I call the operator from the console, I would like the option to provide the list or array of 2D coordinates directly.

**The Question:**
How can I make user provided array/list of 2D coords available to the operator, during its execute?

Comment: Passing a csv file or text document is acutally a good idea and easy to implement. Just declare a `StringProperty` as part of the operator and you're allowed to pass the path as argument when calling your operator in the console. Another option is to pass a comma seperated string... not sure what the max char count is though. However, hard to give an answer without seeing the actual data, suggest add your code and a slim version of the csv table.

Comment: @brockmann, thanks. If I understand your suggestions they are both based on storing the array as a string (either via a StringProperty, or via CSV file). The StringProperty would then be the better option, as this would not require the step of writing to a file. However, consider an array of 1000 pairs of floats, that I would want to write into a string. for each of those 2000 floats, I would need to write them without loosing precision. The solution is sluggish and not pretty. There must be a better way

Comment: If so, then just passing the filepath is most likely the best option and easy to implement as mentioned. Declare `path = bpy.props.StringProperty()` as part of the operator, done. Then you can pass the filepath using the console like so `bpy.ops.mesh.your_custom_op(path="//data.csv")`.

Comment: This misses the point I believe (or I misunderstood). I am interested in creating 2D polygons (potentially alot of them) in python code. Then I would like to run the Operator for each of these created polygons, and make meshes out of all of them. Your suggestion would mean that I would need to use a temporary file (or string variable) where I dump everything first. While this would work, it would be sluggish and yield cryptic code. All I really want is to call the operator, with the actual data. Isnt there some better way? thanks again

Comment: The issue is that there is no real composite data type like an array to pass this huge amount of data when calling the operator using the console: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html There is our famous `CollectionProperty` but this won't help either I guess. If the goal is to create an add-on you can also provide the data in a seperate python file using numpy or something to speed it up a bit. But perhaps I don't get your point, not sure.

Comment: I think you understand me. After quick googling "CollectionProperty", can i do the following?:

Create a class that contains the data of the 2D coordinates of the polygon.
Add a CollectionProperty to my operator
Send this in to the operator manually during console call (making sure i create an instance of the class with the correct coords)